# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, python-unittest, attributeerror

I have been scouring the internet and nitpicking my code but cannot seem to fund where the code failed. I ran the code line by line but there does not seem to be any bugs. This error shows up in the unittest. Python3 is giving me:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_numeric (test_numeric.TestNumeric)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/annahome/Documents/GitHub/DSP_Team8/test_numeric.py", line 16, in test_numeric
    self.assertEqual(dc1.get_unique(),7)
  File "/Users/annahome/Documents/GitHub/DSP_Team8/src/numeric.py", line 26, in get_unique
    return self.serie.dropna().unique.size
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

This is from numeric.py

```
import streamlit as st
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

@dataclass
class NumericColumn:
  col_name: str = None
  serie: pd.Series = None


  def get_name(self):
    """
    Return name of selected column
    """
    return self.col_name

  def get_unique(self):
    """
    Return number of unique values for selected column
    """
    return self.serie.dropna().unique.size

  def get_missing(self):
    """
    Return number of missing values for selected column
    """
    return self.serie.isna().sum()
```

This is from test_numeric.py:

```
import unittest
from src.numeric import NumericColumn
import pandas as pd

class TestNumeric(unittest.TestCase):  
    def test_numeric(self):
        ### test on dummy data ###
        # create series of data
        dc1 = NumericColumn()
        dc1.col_name = "my_test"

        # test methods
        self.assertEqual(dc1.get_name(),"my_test")
        self.assertEqual(dc1.get_unique(),7)
        self.assertEqual(dc1.get_missing(),1)
```

How to I resolve this error? Everything else works fine though...

Comment: your `serie` is None, and you don't assign anything to it. Why would you expect it to change?

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `serie: pd.Series = None` does? In your own words, when `self.serie.dropna()` happens, what is `self.serie` supposed to be? In your own words, what part of your code is supposed to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

In `numeric.py` you declare `serie` and assign `None` to it. Since you don't assign something else to it anywhere in the code, `serie` will remain `None`, therefore you cannot get the attribute `dropna`. Please make sure that you assign a value to `serie` before getting the attribute `dropna`. Please also remember that `serie: pd.Series = None` doesn't mean that `serie` us necessarily of type `pd.Series`, but that it is merely a code *hint* and that it can take a different type, incase you forgot.